# Why deleted rows still show up in a subsequent select query in concurrently executed MySQL transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, mysql-5.7

I have the following `memberships` table with some initial data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE memberships (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT,
    group_id INT
);

INSERT INTO memberships(user_id, group_id) 
    VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);
```

I have two transactions (repeatable read isolation level) deleting all the rows whose `group_id` is 2 from the `memberships` table and retrieving the result using a `select` query, but the result I get is surprising.

| time | transaction 1 | transaction 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | `start transaction` |  |
| T2 | `delete from memberships where group_id = 2` | `start transaction` |
| T3 |  | `select * from memberships` this is to make MySQL believe that transaction 2 starts before transaction 1 finishes |
| T4 | `select * from memberships` this prints only rows whose `group_id` is 1 |  |
| T5 | `commit` |  |
| T6 |  | `delete from memberships where group_id = 2` |
| T7 |  | `select * from memberships` surprisingly, this prints all rows including rows whose `group_id` is 2 |

Below is the result I get from T7.

```
select * from memberships;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |
|  2 |       2 |        1 |
|  3 |       1 |        2 |
|  4 |       2 |        2 |
+----+---------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is really surprising since this `select` query is immediately preceded by a `delete` query which should remove all the rows whose `group_id` is 2.

I tried this on MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, and both of them have this issue.

I also tried this on Postgres 14 (also repeatable read isolation level), fortunately, Postgres doesn't have this issue. At timestamp T6, I get an error `could not serialize access due to concurrent delete`.

Can someone explain to me:

1. Why MySQL has the issue I described above? How does MySQL implement deletion and how does it work with the MySQL MVCC scheme?
2. Why Postgres doesn't have the issue? How does Postgres implement deletion and how does it work with the Postgres MVCC implementation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The repeatable read behavior you are seeing is mentioned in the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read):

> This is the default isolation level for InnoDB. Consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read.

This means that the repeatable snapshot which the second transaction sees throughout its transaction is established at T3.  Keep in mind that repeatable read is the default isolation level for MySQL.

On Postgres, the default isolation level is *not* repeatable read but rather read committed.  Under this isolation level, attempting the delete from the second transaction which interleaves with the first transaction generates the `serialize access` error.  If you explicitly set the isolation level in Postgres you should get similar behavior:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Comment: I am also using repeatable read in postgres by adding "ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ" after "Start Transaction", although not explicitly shown in the SQL statements I mentioned in this question. And the behavior is not similar, I get an error in postgres "could not serialize access due to concurrent delete".

Comment: Well my answer addresses the first part of your question.  The behavior on MySQL is expected.  Not sure why Postgres behaves this way.  Maybe double check your Postgres code and try again.